# Torque for tightening engine bolts

Tags: motorcycle, yamaha, torque-specification

I've ordered [Evotech Performance's engine guard](https://evotech-performance.com/products/yamaha-tracer-700-crash-bobbins-2016-onwards?_pos=3&_sid=92ff0a93d&_ss=r) (or crash bobbins as they apparently call it in the UK) for my **2020 Yamaha Tracer 700** and want to know the correct torque specification necessary to tighten the engine bolts that the guard comes in place-of.

Couldn't find anything in the service manual and from an online search.

Comment: Contact Evotech - they will tell you as well as if you need different bolts. You might well find it all in the instructions that may well come with the guard.

Comment: @SolarMike The instructions by Evotech only state "Manufacturers Torque Specification" which is exactly the reason for my question... :(

Comment: It took me a few minutes to find these [torque settings](https://www.mt07ukowners.co.uk/single-post/Yamaha-MT-07-Torque-Settings) for Yamaha MT-07. If this isn't the right model you could contact that Owner's Club. It even mentions "after market crash bungs fitted".